# Algebraic Grid Generation

Tags: mesh-generation, unstructured-mesh, grid

I am new to the topic " Algebraic Grid Generation". I want to find a simple example where we solve the host equation, let us say the heat equation, numerically in the computational domain then transform it back to the physical domain. All the references I found discuss the general steps without providing a single practical example

Comment: There is a practical example in this paper (in the appendix): Umansky et al., Numerical Heat Transfer, Part B: Fundamentals, 47:6, 533-554 (2005).

Comment: Could you please mention the full informationa about that paper. Authors' names, titke, DOI... or could you please send me the link? Actually I could not find it @MaximUmansky

Comment: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10407790590928946



Umansky, M. & Day, M. & Rognlien, T.. (2005). On Numerical Solution Of Strongly Anisotropic Diffusion Equation On Misaligned Grids. Numerical Heat Transfer Part B - Fundamentals. 47. 533-554. 10.1080/10407790590928946.

Comment: May I contact you via email? @MaximUmansky